# JMeter: Use Command line sh jmeter -n -t <test JMX file> -l <test log file> run test plan does not end on mac

Tags: jmeter, logs

When I run the test plan in JMeter, it is working fine, but use command line `jmeter -n -t <test JMX file> -l <test log file>`, the run cannot stop.

The number of thread user is "1" and loop count is "1"

[image: Screenshot of Thread Group dialog]

[image: Screenshot of HTTP request dialog]

[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JMeter: Command line tests do not end](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16657/jmeter-command-line-tests-do-not-end)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you're suffering from [JMeter issue 6008](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/issues/6008), the workarounds are in:

1. Add `<boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>` to the [.jmx script directly](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan)
2. Downgrade to [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)
3. Upgrade to [JMeter Nightly build](https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html)
4. Wait for next JMeter release 5.6.1 which will contain the fix
5. Switch to another Thread Group like [Open Model Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Open_Model_Thread_Group)